# Map and Flatmap Future[JsValue]

Tags: scala

Im having an issue to extract string value from a Future[JsValue]

I tried Map and Flatmap but i guess im doing somthing wrong...

I have this method that return **Future[JsValue]**

```
 val chunk: Future[JsValue] = BusinessLogic.Methods.getJsonValue(url)
```

If i was map i get a Future[String]

```
 val next: Future[String] = (chunk.map(_.\("paging").\("next").as[String]))
```

If i use flat map i get type mismatch

```
 val next = chunk.flatMap(x=>x.\("paging").\("next").as[String])
```

What will be the correct way to extract the value ??

thanks

Comment: What do you mean extract the value? If you want to unwrap the future you have to block (and depending on what are you trying to do it can be a bad idea). `map` wraps the result of the anonymous function in another future, `flatMap` instead needs you to wrap the result in a future, in both cases the return type is `Future[T]`.

Comment: I have to get the string value out of the future in order to pass it to another method that tack a string

Comment: `next.map(otherFunctionThatTakesAString)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

From oficial tutorials, regarding map:

> One of the basic combinators is map, which, given a future and a
>   mapping function for the value of the future, produces a new future
>   that is completed with the mapped value once the original future is
>   successfully completed.

Regarding flat map.

> The flatMap method takes a function that maps the value to a new future g, and then returns a future which is completed once g is completed.

So in your case since you just want to convert response to some other value, you need a map function, which would map result of your future to String.

```
val next: Future[String] = (chunk.map(_.\("paging").\("next").as[String]))
```

Next value here is a either failure from chunk or result of mapping chunk js value to String.

If you would have some additional asynchronous calculations, like

```
def calculations: (x: String): Future[Int] = ...

val next: Future[Int] = chunk.flatMap(js=> {
   val x = js.\("paging").\("next").as[String]
   calculations(x)
})
```

You would need to use flatMap, combining two dependent asynchronous futures in one. Next value here is a result of calculations function, applied to result returned from chunk.

Comment: I try to it this way but i  go error 
scala recursive call not in tail position

Comment: Can you be more specific. Which one did you try? Are you sure recursive call refers to this map function, not something else?

Comment: this is the recursive method
def inner(url: String, commentList: Future[List[JsValue]]): Future[List[JsValue]] = {
      val chunk: Future[JsValue] = BusinessLogic.Methods.getJsonValue(url)


      val jsList: Future[List[JsValue]] = chunk.map(_.\("data").as[List[JsValue]])


      chunk.flatMap(x => {
        val next = x.\("paging").\("next").as[String]
        if (next != null)

          inner(next, commentList.flatMap(l => jsList.map(l2 => l ++ l2)))
        else
          commentList.flatMap(l => jsList.map(l2 => l ++ l2))
      })
    }
    inner(url, Future.successful(Nil))
  }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unwrap your Future you have to block. This is a very bad idea and should be avoided if possible!

```
def nextFunction(s:String):Unit = ???
val chunk: Future[JsValue] = BusinessLogic.Methods.getJsonValue(url)
val next: String = Await.result(chunk, 1.second)
nextFunction(next)
```

As mentioned above this is a bad idea! The better solution would be:

```
def nextFunction(s:String):Unit = ???
val chunk: Future[JsValue] = BusinessLogic.Methods.getJsonValue(url)
chunk.foreach(nextFunction)
```

This basically calls the nextFunction with the value as soon as it is available and we never have to block.